# Available in 6-packs, 9-packs, 20-packs

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Started with an algorithms problem which says item is sold in 3 different sizes of boxes. These 3 boxes have 6, 9, 20 items each. Input is `n`, figure out if you can buy exactly `n` items.

It got me thinking that there is a number `m`, if `n >= m` then you always can buy `n` items. If you generalize number of items in a box into `s1 s2 s3 ... sy`,
number of boxes to buy into `k1 k2 k3 ... ky`, number of items you want to buy into `n`.

`k1*s1 + k2*s2 + ... + ky*sy = n`

How do I find the value `m`, if `n >= m` there's always gonna be `k1, k2, ..., ky` which satisfies above equation. So that the algorithm can say `yes you can` without doing anything if `n` is large enough.

Comment: This is the [coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).  For two types of coin it is simple.  If the values are $m,n$ and coprime, the largest value you cannot make is $mn-m-n-1$  If there are more, it gets complicated.

Comment: Edited my question, equation was wrong. Please see again :D

Comment: This is still the coin problem, and it is still an open question.  There is a straightforward dynamic programming algorithm to solve the problem in general.

Comment: @MJD Yes I'm aware of dynamic programming algorithm, just wanted to know if there can be a case that there's no need to run the algorithm. Simplest case can be done by using modulo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

- If you have steps $2$ and $3$ then the only numbers you cannot reach is $1$, that is, you can reach any even, and any odd larger or equal 3.
- Similarly, if you have steps $6$ and $9$ then you can reach any number $a$, such that $3 \mid a$ and $a > 3$.
- Now observe that $20 \bmod 3 = 2$ and $40 \bmod 3 = 1$. In other words you can reach any number $b$ such that $3 \mid (b-2)$ and $b \geq 20 + 6$ and any $c$ where $3 \mid (c-1)$ and $c \geq 40 + 6$.
- Getting that together gives, any $k$ for $k \geq 46$.
- Direct checking can tell you that you can also reach 
  \begin{align} \{
  &0, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, \\
  &26, 27, 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, \\
  &38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45
  \}.\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: given 6 9 20 how do you come up with 3? Common divisor of 6 9 or 9-6 or something else?

Comment: $3$ is a common factor, so any combination of $6$ and $9$ will be divisible by $3$. In fact $\gcd(6,9)=3$.

Comment: Given that you can reach 44 and 45, shouldn't we have $k \geq 44$?

Comment: @Sal That would be true too, but it wouldn't follow from previous bullets. The reason given in the proof for $k \geq 46$ is different than for $k \in \{44, 45\}$, and that's why it is written as it is.

Comment: @dtldarek I agree that from point 3, you have $k \geq 46$ *specifically for* $3|(k-1)$, and this is the highest bound directly, but working mod $3$ suggests exploring the two lower numbers ($45, \ 44$) as lowest upper bounds. By point 1, you have $k\geq6$ when $3|k$, which includes $45$. By point 3, you have $k\geq 26$ when $3|(k-2)$, which includes $44$. Repeating the process, $43$ is unreachable. I don't mean to sound pedantic; I really like your answer!